# accidentally deleted all my desktop directories after I did "git clean -f -d" to remove untracked files

Tags: git

is there a way I can recover them. I am panicking rn
I am using a Mac.
I was using IntelliJ when I saw some untracked file and I used the command "git clean -f -d" to remove all the untracked files and accidentally deleted all the directories on my desktop.

Comment: @Luksprog where do I find this folder (.git/lost-found/other) as the the link mentioned ?

Comment: @AryanArora `ls -la` with commands and this is in the directory the project

Comment: @NicolásAlarcónR. only folders I can see on terminal after executing ur command and then cd into .git are these (COMMIT_EDITMSG  ORIG_HEAD hooks  logs
FETCH_HEAD config  index  objects
HEAD  description info  refs)